# Why is this Python function not working?

Tags: python

Keeps returning "You are older than some hills" even if i input less than 30

```
age = raw_input("What age are you?") 
def old(n):
  if n >= 30:
    print "You are older than some hills"
  else:
    print "Youth"

old(age)
```

Answer (score 8):

Because you forgot to convert your input to a number, as it stands it is a string, and in Python 2 any string is always greater than any number.

Use `int(raw_input("What age are you?"))`

(Python 3 throws an error when you try to compare a string and a number, which is a good design decision.)

Answer (score 0):

The `raw_input()` function uses the input as strings, therefore, you should convert the input to `int` type.

```
age = int(raw_input("What age are you?")) 
def old(n):
if n >= 30:
  print "You are older than some hills"
else:
  print "Youth"

old(age)
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to convert the input to an integer. However, if the user inputs a letter, the program will throw an error. To make sure this doesn't happen, I would recommend getting the input using try and except, this can be done as follows:

```
age = raw_input("What age are you?") 
try:
    int(age)
except ValueError:
    print('That is not a number')
```